# How to create foreign key if records are already available in table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, phpmyadmin

- I am using phpMyAdmin
- I have created 2 tables,Table1 and Table2.
- In Table1 (id) is a primary key and I forgot to create the foreign
  key in Table2 and added all records on the table2.

Question:

If there are no records in the table2 then I can create a foreign key but how can we create the foreign key if there are records.

I have to create the foreign key in Table2. I tried below query

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_User_id
FOREIGN KEY(User_id) REFERENCES Table1(Id)
```

I am getting error in phpMyadmin

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Please see my updated answer, which highlights some potential problems with the marked answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st Step,

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 
ADD User_id1 int
```

2nd Step,

```
ALTER TABLE Table2 
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_User_id1
FOREIGN KEY(User_id1) REFERENCES Table1(Id)
```

3rd Step ,

```
update Table2 set User_id1 =User_id
```

See 3rd Step error is valid.since earlier there was no FK there were some invalid data that got inserted.

you can run this query,

```
select [user_id] from table2 A
where not exists(select id from table1 B where b.[user_id]=a.id)
```

--you will get some record here
--when you delete these record
-- then 3rd step will run fine.you decide

If it is still in development phase then you can delete these records.
OR

Sadly you can't create FK now.You can still create Instead of trigger on table2

Performance wise both are same.

Comment: your error indicate that u r not running my scripts. see i hv created new column,then added new constraint name FK_User_id1

Comment: Mr.KumarHarsh, I am getting error in 3rd step.Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Right KumarHarsh, I tried again but getting issue in 3rd step.

Comment: Mr.KumarHarsh, I have one doubt.Can I delete column name User_id which I created before because there is no use of it.

Comment: Because using you query User_id1 is created, which is foreign key

Comment: yes,if everything is success then you can Delete user_id. i forgot to write Step 4

Comment: @NarendraVerma i don't agree with this answer as it's effectively ignoring data. You can have a valid record in table 2 with NULL for the foreign key if there is nothing to join to, adding the constraint will work with NULLS. This answer is asking you to delete some of your data with, which you didn't ask for as you have specified 0 as the default I would assume this may not be desired. For future users also, this wouldn't be advice anyone can follow, as i stated before, it's recommending deleting of data that might not be valid for deletion.

Comment: @Tanner ,I agree with you.I don't know why Default NULL value point slip out of my mind.

Comment: Is this the recommended way of checking for valid data?
```select [user_id] from table2 A
where not exists(select id from table1 B where b.[user_id]=a.id)```

Answer (score 2):

Your error says that it can't create the foreign key because there are some values that it can't map. So make sure all referenced data in Table2 exists in the primary key of Table1 before you do this.

Query the distinct values from each table and see what the difference is and fix the data before trying to rerun the alter script.

**Update after your comment:**

> In Table2, I have create User_id column and its take default value 0

In response to your above comment, you should use `NULL` as the default value instead of `0` and it should work. You will need to run an update script like this to change the `0` values to `NULL`:

```
UPDATE Table2
SET User_Id = NULL 
WHERE User_Id = 0
```

The marked answer is suggesting deleting data that doesn't reference a record in Table1, but this could be dangerous as the records in Table2 could be valid in not joining to Table1.

For example, assume Table1 is `CarBuyer` and Table2 is `CarsForSale`. `CarsForSale` has a column for the person that buys a car, which is only populated when the car is purchased, otherwise it should be `NULL`. With the other answer, the suggestion is to delete all cars that don't have an buyer.

Comment: In Table2, I have create User_id column and its take default value 0.